# How to give style a child component of normal component at Styled Components lib

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

There are few questions very similar to this but I couldn't find my answer. I want to give style to a *styled component* which is inside of a normal react component without using extra wrapper.

```
const Child = styled.div`
  background: gray;
`;

const Foo = () => (<div> I am foo <Child> Child</Child> </div>)

const Parent = styled(Foo)`
  ${Child} {
      background: pink;
      color: pink;
  }
`;
```

And I want to use `Parent` component somewhere with desired style of `Child`. Here I expected to override `Child` component's background, but it didn't work.

[example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-l5a7ku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `className` prop so the styles would be injected, it mentioned in many other answers and in docs:

```
const Foo = ({ className }) => (
  <div className={className}>
    I am foo <Child> Child</Child>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const App =()=> {
 
    return (
      <div>
        <Hello name={'Reacr'} />
        <p>Start editing to see some magic happen :)</p>
        <Parent > I am foo <Child> Child</Child></Parent>
      </div>
    );
  }


const Child = styled.div`
  color: black;
`;
const Parent = ({children,...props}) => (
  <ParentStyle  {...props} >
    {children}
  </ParentStyle >
);


const ParentStyle = styled.div`
  background: gray;
  ${Child} {
    background: pink;
    color: black;
  }
`;
```

check the fork in the example app